# HTTPHEAD in combination with HTTPGET for calculated file

Tags: http, http-headers

I am having an API endpoint, e,g, `https://localhost:8741/api/someUrl/68`

where `68` is an ID and is used to go to the database and using some query, calculate an actual file on the file system. The problem now is that when a third party library is given this endpoint, it first calls an HTTP HEAD request (I assume this is not specific to this library, but a general HTTP practice).

This HEAD request thus as a consequence, makes my server do a database access to calculate the actual path, only to return the CONTENT-LENGTH for the response headers.

And next, the actual GET request is done, making my server go yet again to the database and redo the calculations. This is a big code smell it seems, doing all this work twice.

One way to counter this is to introduce caching, but I am wondering what the best practices are in this scenario. Is this HEAD really necessary? Is it bad when I make the HEAD just return a fake `Content-length: 0` header?